# 実装されているスムーススクロールに邪魔されてタブの実装ができません

Tags: javascript

運用しているサイトに[**このスムーススクロール**](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js)が実装されています。
サイトはCMSを使用しており、ボディの一部分のみ編集可能です。そのため、cssやjavascriptはbody内に記述しています。
この度コンテンツにタブを組み込むことになったのですが、上記のスムーススクロールが邪魔をしてタブをクリックするとスムーススクロールのイベントが発生してしまいます。
body内からスムーススクロールのファイルを編集してタブを実装することは可能でしょうか。できればタブ以外はスムーススクロールをそのまま活用したいと考えています。
ご教授の程宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: タブの実装はどうやっていますか？ コードを出せますか？ スクロールのJavaScriptが読み込まれるタイミングはいつですか？

Answer (score 0):

詳細がないので予想なのですが
スムーススクロールの実装として#が含まれているハッシュリンク（）にjsが反応してスクロールしてしまっているのではないかと思います。

ですのでタブの実装でのような実装にすればjsが実行されないかと思います。

もしくは違うスムーススクロールプラグインを使ってtab内の#には反応しないような記述ができるプラグインを使用することで解決できるのではないかと思います。